# How to check for valid sentence using index values in a file in Java

Tags: java

I have a following Begin and End indexes of sentences in a file.

```
Begin:1583 End:1631
Begin:2284 End:2324
```

Now i have to check whether these indexes are existed in a valid sentence by reading a particular file.I have tried with BreakIterator.But i did not understand how can i check the above indexes are existed in a valid sentence.

The code i have tried is

```
public class Breakiterator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String sCurrentLine = null;
    String l=null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/test.txt "));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            BreakIterator i=BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
            i.setText(sCurrentLine);
            for(int s=i.first(), e=i.next(); e>=0; s=e, e= i.next())
            {
              System.out.println("Sentence: from "+s+" to "+e+" \""+sCurrentLine.substring(s, e)+'"');
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What does this mean : `Now i have to check whether these indexes are existed in a valid sentence` ???

Comment: How about setting up an appropriate regex, and check whether or not the whole sentence matches it?

Comment: @peeskillet :For example i have  one sentence "mr.Pat and mr.nixon are living in boston" with start and end index.By using these indexes i have to check whether it is valid sentence or not.

Comment: @peeskillet:do you need more details?

Comment: @sara I still don't understand the concept of what the `BEGIN` and `END` indices are for. Also, look at answer below to see if that helps.

Comment: @sara, one thing I noticed is your class name is `Breakiterator` and you're trying to create a `BreakIterator` object. Two different things. The `I` and `i` make a huge difference.  A huge uncompilable difference.

Comment: @peeskillet:Those are the locations in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Modify your regular expression as per your requirement

```
 public static final String VALID_LINE_REG_EXP = "\\w+:\\d+.\\w+:\\d+";
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String sCurrentLine = null;
        String l = null;
        boolean isValid;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Shamse.txt "));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine.trim().matches(VALID_LINE_REG_EXP));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have written this code assuming that your file will contains values in `TEXT:NUMBER TEXT:NUMBER` you can modify this regular expression as per your requirement

Comment: splitting the lines of file with "space" or with ":" we can not believe that it is a valid sentence. What if the lines of has period in between.

Comment: You can simply write a regular expresison and solve this problem

Comment: You just write a regular expression and match the sentence with that. in this case u will not need to split the sentence